# Join table and Case sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem in my SQL Select , for example we have two users X and Y , user X want to see user Y Following so , when see his following , 
user Y want to know who users in user X (following) follow them 
in this picture : https://i.imgsafe.org/d2b2d83886.png user with id :68 want to see users.id = 50 Following

```
SELECT users.id,users.username,
    CASE WHEN follows.user_id = 68 THEN 1 END AS is_Follow
FROM users
LEFT JOIN follows
    ON follows.follower_id = users.id
WHERE follows.app = 1 AND follows.user_id = 50
```

but this return me NULL :( what should i do ?!

Answer (score 2):

Conditions on the `right` table of a `LEFT JOIN` should be on the `ON` clause and not on the `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT users.id,users.username,
    CASE WHEN follows.user_id = 68 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END AS is_Follow --Minus one value means NO.
FROM users
LEFT JOIN follows
    ON follows.follower_id = users.id AND
       follows.app = 1 AND
```

Another thing, what exactly are you checking? How many people follow `user_id=68` ? Because by the name of the column it doesn't sounds like it.

**EDIT:** Try this:

```
SELECT users.id,users.username,
    MAX(CASE WHEN follows.user_id = 68 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS is_Follow --Minus one value means NO.
FROM users
LEFT JOIN follows
    ON follows.follower_id = users.id AND
       follows.app = 1 AND
GROUP BY users.id,users.username
```

Comment: thanks, but this isn't correct answer :( this return NULL

Comment: That's probably because you are not doing it correct! What is this column meant to be? Becuase for now its an indication if this user is following `user_id=68` or not.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, what do you want to achieve? Your query is doing what it needs to.

Comment: because i don't want to NULL in id and UserName what should i do for this !! thanks <3

Comment: Just explain to me what is this column `is_Follow` supposed to represent ?

Comment: if u look at Instagram when i see your profile for example your followers if i someone in your followers i followed Instagram show me you follow this person !

Comment: @kamyab Try my query as it is now.

Comment: actually when user_id 68 see the following of user_id 50 if user_id 68 follow them  , then write you follow this person too !!

Comment: if you look at this : https://i.imgsafe.org/d4734e4e76.png user_id 50 follow "kamyab_beygi" but if user_id 68 follow his too !!

Comment: i want write message in user_id 68 you follow this person too

Comment: Haha, I found the problem. You are filtering `WHERE follows.user_id = 50` , so of course no body will be equal to 68!

Comment: i'm sorry for disturbing you , i don't want this result !! look this maybe you can understand : https://i.imgsafe.org/d50a235964.png this picture is following of user_id 50 so user_id 68 follow this preson too !! then is is_follow should be ONE not -1

Comment: God damit then stop using this query!@ `COPY PASTE` my second query